# Visible formula

Tags: vb.net, vba, excel

I try to load value from CSV file to Excel by VB. I have some problems about, I can calculate and display in Excel. However, in this case I want to display the formula when I click that cell.

For example: A1: `3`, B1: `4`, C1: `=A1 + B1`

Whenever column A and B have values it will automatically calculate in VB already, but I want to click in to C1 or C2. It will show the formula how to calculate it.

Comment: @pnuts: Hi. I write it in excel vb developer.

Comment: Show your actual code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change a cell's formula in VBA you just update its Formula property:

```
Range("C1").Formula = "=A1+B1"
```

Screenshot:
  [image]

Comment: Hi. But in Excel sheet, if I click to the "C1", It won't show the formula. It just shows the sum result.

Comment: You can only see the formula in the formula bar (below the toolbar).